# Return value of waitpid

Tags: c, linux, unix, system, wait

I am using waitpid(2) to check and mark the status of my processes of my job control program. I am using the WUNTRACED option, to catch useful signal like SIGTSTP in a job control program.

The problem is, when CTRL-Z (SIGTSTP) my program, the PID returned by waitpid(2) is correct (>0), but when killing it with a CTRL-C (SIGINT), the PID returned is -1. How is that ? How can I mark the status of my process then ? Since it return an invalid PID and set errno to ECHILD.

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>

int     main(void)
{
    pid_t   pid;
    pid_t   ret;
    int     stat_loc;

    if ((!(pid = fork())))
    {
        execve("/bin/ls", (char *const []){"ls", "-Rl", "/", NULL}, NULL);
    }
    else if (pid > 0)
    {
        signal(SIGINT, SIG_IGN);
        signal(SIGQUIT, SIG_IGN);
        signal(SIGTSTP, SIG_IGN);
        signal(SIGTTIN, SIG_IGN);
        signal(SIGTTOU, SIG_IGN);
        signal(SIGCHLD, SIG_IGN);
        ret = waitpid(-1, &stat_loc, WUNTRACED);
        printf("\nwaitpid returned %d\n", ret);
    }
    return (0);
}
```

EDIT: Problem solved, see the trick with SIGCHLD when you ignore it.

Comment: `waitpid` return -1 on error, do `perror("waitpid")` to see why `waitpid` fails

Comment: clearly read the manual, -1 is not always an error.

Comment: My man page says: *RETURN VALUE: waitpid(); ... On error, -1 is returned.* so yeah, I'm not wrong,  `waitpid` failed (hence it returned -1) because you are ignoring `SIGCHILD`, see Andrew's answer. Though I must confess that I didn't know the reason as why it fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're ignoring `SIGCHLD`:

```
signal(SIGCHLD, SIG_IGN);
```

[Per POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_13):

> Status information for a process shall be generated (made available to
>   the parent process) when the process stops, continues, or terminates
>   except in the following case:
>
> - If the parent process sets the action for the `SIGCHLD` signal to `SIG_IGN`, or if the parent sets the `SA_NOCLDWAIT` flag for the
>     `SIGCHLD` signal action, process termination shall not generate new
>     status information but shall cause any existing status information for
>     the process to be discarded.

If you want to `wait()` on a child process, you can't ignore `SIGCHLD`.